# Ssrs date picker not working in chrome and edge

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, rdl

I am using a field in my ssrs rdl as date/time and when I run it in chrome/edge then it shows only as a text field but in internet explorer it shows up as a date picker.

Please help how to fix it.it should show up as a date picker in chrome and edge also

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ssrs+datepicker+chrome

Comment: Are you really using SSRS 2008? If so, time to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Browser default language couse date parametrs to break and I`ve seen some expression break too due browser language.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).